# Scanner nextline() only printing new lines

Tags: java

I'm trying to use scanner to print lines from a text file, but it only prints first line before printing only new lines until while loop goes through file.

```
String line;
File input = new File("text.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
while (scan.hasNext()) //also does not work with hasNextLine(), but additional error
{
line = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(line);
//other code can see what is in the string line, but output from System.out.println(line); is just a new line
}
```

How can I get System.out.println() to work with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Javadoc for [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

You want [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) instead:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

Your code becomes:

```
while (scan.hasNext())
{
  line = scan.next();
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use **.next()** method:

```
String line;
File input = new File("text.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
while (scan.hasNext()) //also does not work with hasNextLine(), but additional error
{
    line = scan.next();
    System.out.println(line);
}
```